# TFTP "put" works with files in pwd but fails with absolute pathnames

Tags: debian, file-server, tftp

The following command works as expected:

```
tftp <tftp_server_name> -c put some_file
```

However, the following command fails:

```
tftp <tftp_server_name> -c put /absolute/path/to/some_file
```

And, the error message is different for different files. Sometimes it reads

```
Error code 1: File not found
```

and sometimes it reads

```
tftp: some_file: No such file or directory
```

tftp -V reports:

```
tftp-hpa 5.0, without readline
```

in.tftpd -V reports:

```
tftp-hpa 5.2, with remap, with tcpwrappers
```

tftpd is configured with --create and --secure. TFTP_DIRECTORY is set to a directory that is rwx for everyone and is owned by the "nobody" user.
The server is running on Debian wheezy, the client is running on Debian squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to explicitly give a destination filename.
e.g.

```
tftp <tftp_server_name> -c put /absolute/path/to/some_file  some_file
```

Also, note that if you want to send a file to a subdirectory on the server, the subdirectory must already exist on the server and be rwx for all users.

e.g.
If you want to do this

```
tftp <tftp_server_name> -c put /absolute/path/to/some_file  some_dir/some_file
```

then on the server, the directory some_dir must exist in the TFTP_DIRECTORY. (And some_dir must be rwx for everybody.)